# Method to merge two queues in a particular order

Tags: java, merge, queue

```
private ArrayQueue<E> merge( ArrayQueue<E> q1, ArrayQueue<E> q2 ) throws ArrayQueueException 
{
    ArrayQueue<E> mergeQueue = new ArrayQueue<E>( q1.size() + q2.size() );

    ArrayQueue<E> smallestQueue = smallestQueue( q1, q2 );
    ArrayQueue<E> biggestQueue = biggestQueue( q1, q2 );

    for ( int index = 0; index < smallestQueue.size(); index++ )
    {
        E elementOne = smallestQueue.dequeue();
        E elementTwo = biggestQueue.dequeue();

        if ( elementOne.compareTo( elementTwo ) < 0 )
        {
            mergeQueue.enqueue( elementOne );
            mergeQueue.enqueue( elementTwo );
        }
        else
        {
            mergeQueue.enqueue( elementTwo );
            mergeQueue.enqueue( elementOne );
        }
    } 

    for ( int index = 0; index < biggestQueue.size(); index++ )
    {
        mergeQueue.enqueue( biggestQueue.dequeue() );
    }

    return ( mergeQueue );
}
```

I have been attemting an exercise which involves creating a method to merge two queues. My attempt above works when both queues are the same size however it is wrong otherwise.

What would be the best way to implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: Where's the javadoc for ArrayQueue? It's not a standard Java class, so all we can do without javadoc is guess how it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the only problem with your method.

Pseudocode of the correct method looks like this:

```
while (both queues are not empty) {
    retrieve first elements without removing them from their queues
    compare them
    put the appropriate element into the new queue and remove it from its old queue
}

if any of old queues is not empty, put its elements into the new queue
```